# pass prop value to computed properties inside a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

Is it possible/good practice to use a prop value inside a computed property function inside a component? If so, how do I build the return with this prop?

**Carousel.vue**

```
props: [
  'source',
],
computed: {
   items () {
     return this.$store.state.(prop value source here).list
   }
}
```

**store/categorya.js**
(the same for categoryb and categoryc)

```
import categorya from '(...)'
export const state = () => ({
  list: categorya
})
```

---

**Update**

**Index.vue**

```
carousel(source="categorya")
carousel(source="categoryb")
carousel(source="categoryc")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you wanted the list it would be `this.$store.state.list`

Comment: your first code totally solved my problem.
I just want to search for the specific store, according to the value of the prop to populate Carousel.vue component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear.  If source specifies a Vuex module name you could use bracket notation:

```
computed: {
  items () {
    return this.$store.state[this.source].list
  }
}
```

## AFTER YOUR EDIT

Still unclear, but if there are no modules and `list` is a property of root state, then you would simply use:

```
computed: {
  items () {
    return this.$store.state.list
  }
}
```

The fact that `list` is first defined by an import called `categorya` makes no difference.  It's still the only state available and its name is just `list`.